# Resistor combining problem

Tags: resistors, homework

[image]

How can I get I1? I tried combining the two 10 ohms resistors on the right and up in parallel but I always end up getting 2A which is a wrong answer.

Comment: Wait. It should be 2A. My bad.

Comment: @JasonHan actually the answer is 3A but I don’t know where it came from

Comment: If you make equations for each node current and voltage, you can solve this.  But you can see immediately the BR corner is 20V if supply has 0V on V-.  Or you can convert to Norton easily. 1 node shorted to V+

Comment: I ended up with a lot of equations and I couldn’t solve them @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlW1T.png

Comment: The current that pass thru R1 is 2A. You need to find current that goes to R4. Hint: R2//R4.

Comment: It's visually obvious it's 3A. We have two current paths. One goes from the supply through the I1 wire and then through the bottom resistor. That's obviously 2A (20/10). The other goes from the supply through both 10 ohm resistors (top and right) to the junction on the upper right corner then through the 5 ohm resistor to negative. That's also 2A (the two 10 ohm resistors in parallel are 5 ohms and that's in series with the 5 ohm resistor). Half of that goes through I1 and half just goes through the top 10 ohm resistor. So 1A more through I1. Hence 3A total. Okay, maybe not so obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redraw the circuit to make things more clear, then solve.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxLDFE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, finally got 3A.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But why didn’t the solving method I mentioned in the question not getting the answer right?

Comment: Because while those two 10Ω resistors are in parallel, I1 only passes through one of them. That's 1A, plus there's another 2A flowing through the remaining 10Ω resistor.